# Unexpected scoping issue using \XeTeXinterchartoks

Tags: macros, xetex, tex-core, grouping

Minimal example (compile with `xetex`):

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \classa
\XeTeXcharclass `\a \classa
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \classa = {\begingroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \classa 255 = {\endgroup}

\def\foo{\csname MaybeUndefined\endcsname}

\tracingall

a\foo

\bye
```

What I get:

```
{the letter a}
{horizontal mode: the letter a}
\XeTeXinterchartoks->\begingroup 
{\begingroup}
{entering semi simple group (level 1) at line 11}
{the letter a}

\foo ->\csname MaybeUndefined\endcsname 
{\csname}
{changing \MaybeUndefined=undefined}
{into \MaybeUndefined=\relax}
{\relax}
\XeTeXinterchartoks->\endgroup 
{\endgroup}
{restoring \MaybeUndefined=undefined}
{leaving semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 11}
{undefined}
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \MaybeUndefined 

l.11 a\foo
```

Here, `\csname MaybeUndefined\endcsname` should expand to `\MaybeUndefined` and then `\relax`. However, after inserting an `\endgroup` by `\XeTeXinterchartoks`, `\MaybeUndefined` is undefined again after the group. Then the unexpected error occurs.

What can I do?

Comment: I would say it depends which part of the code is under your control. You can add a `\relax` at the start of `\foo`. But if `\foo` represents an arbitrary command then imho you are out of luck: xetex has to go forth to check if the next input is a word boundary and then must go "back" to insert your `\endgroup`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Well, we are developing packages rely on `\XeTeXinterchartoks`, but we cannot determine how users use it. So it is not possible to add `\relax` before `\foo`. For some cases, I can reimplement `\@namedef` to avoid the problem, but that's not enough.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you convert your comment to an answer? I believe that this cannot be solved in full generality.

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends which part of the code is under your control. You can add a `\relax` at the start of `\foo`. But if `\foo` represents an arbitrary command then imho you are out of luck: xetex has to go forth to check if the next input is a word boundary and then must go "back" to insert your `\endgroup`.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that \expandafter{\csname anything\endcsname} expands to an undefined control sequence, not to \relax, so this is what you see.